# YouTrackSharp - EasyHttp Bad Request

Tags: c#, youtrack, youtracksharp

I am occasionally receiving a bad request error message when making API requests via YouTrackSharp. This only happens when running on the server, if I debug the app locally (running on IIS, not IIS Express), it goes through appropriately. Has anyone experienced this behavior before, and any suggestions?

**Exception**

```
YouTrackSharp.Infrastructure.InvalidRequestException: Bad Request ---> EasyHttp.Infrastructure.HttpException: BadRequest Bad Request
   at EasyHttp.Http.HttpClient.ProcessRequest(String filename)
   at YouTrackSharp.Infrastructure.Connection.MakePostRequest(String command, Object data, String accept)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
   at YouTrackSharp.Issues.IssueManagement.ApplyCommand(String issueId, String command, String comment, Boolean disableNotifications, String runAs)
```

---

**Calling Code**

```
issueManagement.ApplyCommand(issue.Id,
  string.Format("Ready For Testing Versions {0}", version),
  string.Format("Marked Ready for Testing for {0} build, compiled {1}, by {2}",
  version, utcDate.ToLocalTime(), user.UserName),
  true);
```

---

```
public void ApplyCommand(string issueId, string command, string comment, bool disableNotifications = false, string runAs = "")
{
    if (!_connection.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        throw new InvalidRequestException(Language.YouTrackClient_CreateIssue_Not_Logged_In);
    }

    try
    {
        dynamic commandMessage = new ExpandoObject();


        commandMessage.command = command;
        commandMessage.comment = comment;
        if (disableNotifications)
            commandMessage.disableNotifications = disableNotifications;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(runAs))
            commandMessage.runAs = runAs;

        _connection.Post(string.Format("issue/{0}/execute", issueId), commandMessage);
    }
    catch (HttpException httpException)
    {
        throw new InvalidRequestException(httpException.StatusDescription, httpException);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you easily reproduce this? if yes can you use Fiddler to see what the request is ?

Comment: easily? no, but when it does occur, it usually happens multiple times, so i'll see what i can do about getting a fiddler capture and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being an odd way the YouTrack API was executing the command I was using.  I happened across the YouTrack logs, and the error was being logged there. Word to the wise: check the YouTrack logs when you see this error message.